# REACT Context API provider returns undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm new with react. When I try to access to provider's values it only returns the first one and the others return as undefined. This is my provider code:

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const MyProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ stages: 0, values: [] });
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={[state, setState]}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default MyProvider;
export const AppContext = createContext();
```

Comment: Can You share with us your context consumer component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting provider object properly. Try this example out:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const AppContext = createContext();

const MyProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ stages: 0, values: [] });
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, setState }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <MyProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <SetterComponent />
        <ConsumerComponent />
      </div>
    </MyProvider>
  );
}

const ConsumerComponent = () => {
  const { state } = useContext(AppContext);
  return (
    <div>
      {state.stages} -- {JSON.stringify(state.values)}
    </div>
  );
};

const SetterComponent = () => {
  const { state, setState } = useContext(AppContext);

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() =>
        setState({
          stages: state.stages + 1,
          values: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)
        })
      }
    >
      Set Next Stage
    </button>
  );
};
```

Here is the code sandbox link to play with this example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-merkle-omccp

Comment: Thank you friend, It worked :D, I also was calling it wrong `cause I only consumed one of the values instead of the two at same time. 
I was doing this: 

setState({ stage: state.stage - 1 })
setState({ values: [] })

Instead of this

setState({
      stage: state.stage - 1,
      values: [state.values.shift()]
    })

Answer (score 0):

Give it as `value={{state, setState}}`.
And please provide us with the consumer component.